# Hashicorp Vault token doesn't look like UUID

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have been following Hashicorp vault tutorial but something look different on my environment. For instance in the tutorial whenever we create token, the token looks like a UUID.
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/token/create.html
`95eba8ed-f6fc-958a-f490-c7fd0eda5e9e`

But this is not the case in my system.

```
vault token create -ttl 5m
Key                  Value
---                  -----
token                s.Cis96Ler69uhmW6EyH4VYf6o
token_accessor       DlgCcsP7qn6hyfdR8S8ULjRp
token_duration       5m
token_renewable      true
token_policies       ["root"]
identity_policies    []
policies             ["root"]
```

What configuration did I missed? is there a benefit using the UUID format over the s.xxxxx?

I'm using `Vault v1.0.2 ('37a1dc9c477c1c68c022d2084550f25bf20cac33')` on a MacOS

Answer (score 0):

Vault token are not UUIDs. They are a 128-bit pure random number.

From the documentation:

> Generates UUID-format strings using high quality, purely random bytes.
>   It is not intended to be RFC compliant, merely to use a
>   well-understood string representation of a 128-bit value. It can also
>   parse UUID-format strings into their component bytes.

see this [discussion](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/1707) for more details. and [hashicorp/go-uuid](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-uuid) package if you want to understand how this is implemented.

Comment: `s.Cis96Ler69uhmW6EyH4VYf6o` is not a UUID-format string, though, is it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens) documentation:

> Note that external to Vault, tokens are to be considered opaque values by users and as such, their structure is both currently undocumented and subject to change.

So you should not assume anything about the structure or content of the token. It is true that tokens once have "looked" like UUIDs, but as noted in another answer even then they technically wheren't.

You should just treat it as a string of characters and not worry about the format. That being said however: the token format changed in vault 0.11.2 (see [changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0112-october-2nd-2018))